# Make multi-stage docker file to use container from remote machine (RDP)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-multi-stage-build

I want to make a multi-stage docker file to access base container from remote machine (using RDP).
The Base Image:
The base image itself driven from [freqtrade](https://github.com/freqtrade/freqtrade) project to include Jupyter Lab. Here are the files:

docker-compose file:

```
---
version: '3'
services:
  ft_jupyterlab:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.jupyter
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: ft_jupyterlab
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - "./user_data:/freqtrade/user_data"
    # Default command used when running `docker compose up`
    command: >
      jupyter lab --port=8888 --ip 0.0.0.0 --allow-root --NotebookApp.token=''
```

and Dockerfile.jupyter:

```
# Use the base image from the first image
FROM freqtradeorg/freqtrade:develop_plot

# Pin prompt-toolkit to avoid questionary version conflict
RUN pip install jupyterlab "prompt-toolkit<=3.0.36" jupyter-client --user --no-cache-dir
ENTRYPOINT []
```

I need add prepared docker file included xfce and xrdp, [scottyhardy/docker-remote-desktop](https://github.com/scottyhardy/docker-remote-desktop) to above docker file. Note that docker-remote-desktop has `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/entrypoint"]` ([source](https://github.com/scottyhardy/docker-remote-desktop/blob/master/Dockerfile))